# Slow update of elastic ip dns in internal network

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elastic-ip

I attached an elastic ip to an ec2 instance. When I move the elastic ip to another instance(because of a failure for example), the IP is updated in about 10 seconds to point to the new instance. 
The problem is, that I reach the elastic ip through its public dns, and it seems that it doesn't update to the new ip for about 3 minutes.
How can I make this transition faster without using the ip address directly?

Answer (score 0):

There is a TTL (time to live) on the dns records.  It sounds like it has been set to 180 seconds or greater.  You need to decrease TTL in your public DNS record.

[AWS Route53 Information on TTL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-basic.html#rrsets-values-basic-ttl)

Using the dig command you can see what the current value for amazon.com is 51 seconds.  Note, multiple queries to amazon.com will produce different results.

```
$ dig console.aws.amazon.com
[ OUTPUT REMOVED FOR CLARITY ]
;; ANSWER SECTION:
amazon.com.     51  IN  A   205.251.242.103
amazon.com.     51  IN  A   176.32.98.166
amazon.com.     51  IN  A   176.32.103.205
```